# Exception handling : Thread v/s Task

Tags: c#

Thread version results in unhandled exception, which crashes the app but the task version doesn't. Both are running exactly the same method Can someone explain the reason for this difference in exception behavior ?

Thread version:

```
            try
            {
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork)).Start();  // do work throws exception
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

        static void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in thread");
            throw new Exception();
        }
```

Task version:

```
      var errorTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<Func<string>>(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("in task");
                    throw new Exception();
                });

            try
            {
                string result = errorTask.Result();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
```

Comment: Because Tasks != Threads.

Comment: @john Yeah, but for a novice the behavior is quite similar, hence it is conceivable that xe is irritated by the way exceptions are handled differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thread.Start` starts new thread, but you're handling exception in another thread:

```
try
{
    // DoWork throws exception in new thread;
    // threads don't catch exceptions out-of-the-box
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork)).Start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // you're handling exception in "old" thread
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

`Task.Factory.StartNew` starts new *task*. Task catches exception inside it to set its [`Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.status(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
var errorTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<Func<string>>(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("in task");

    // this exception will be caught in Task's base code,
    // since tasks catch exceptions thrown by task methods;
    // note, that this will be wrapped into AggregateException
    throw new Exception();
});
```

when you're trying to get `Task.Result`, and task is in faulted state, it just re-throws exception:

```
// this will re-throw exception in calling thread
string result = errorTask.Result;
```

That's why your second `catch` catches it.

Answer (score 1):

To shed some light on the topic one could consult the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Task.Result<TResult>()` (or the one for [`Task.Wait()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) for what it's worth).

Under thrown exceptions (particularly `AggregateException`) is says

> An exception was thrown during the execution of the task. The `AggregateException.InnerExceptions` collection contains information about the exception or exceptions.

A `Task` is kind of a managed thread (in very simple terms) which gives us some merits, e.g. this exception handling when accessing `Result` or `Wait` (or using `await`). On the other hand a `Thread` will execute separately from the method you are calling it from. You start the thread an (virtually) immediately leave the `try / catch` block. There is no way to *know* for the thread that there is an associated `try / catch`. Basically the thread does not know anything about the calling function. The other way round, if the calling function blocked its own thread to wait for the thread it created, just to make use of the `try / catch` this would basically render creating new threads useless.